# Google Calendar "URL is too long to process and That's all we know" error

Tags: google-calendar

I recently received an email from Google (it was an email address ending with `@google.com`) On the right hand side of my gmail, there was a link `Add event to Google Calendar`. Upon clicking this link, I received the following error message. What could be the reason for this and how do I resolve this issue?

[image: Error message when I tried to add an event]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the information about this error **[FIX: "414 Request-URI Too Large" Error Message from ISA Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819962)** and **[HTTP Error 414 Request URI too long](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E414.html)**

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer isn't actually a solution.

I ran into this problem recently, and I made a simple Chrome Extension that fixes the problem, at least for Google Calendar. It uses the webRequest API to shorten the URL automatically after you click the link.

You can download it [on the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/anfemphbgknehemmbbajjcmakfijiohp).

Comment: doesn't look like they were looking for a solution, but rather answer for why this was happening. As such, you've posted a good workaround and it's a valid one.

Comment: Upvoted for the solution. As @Dez said, I was actually more interested in the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I know you aren't asking for a solution, but I came to this page hoping I could find one.  Maybe this will help someone else...

It's not an ideal solution, but I've discovered a work-around for the same issue my company has been having with sharing multiple calendars.  If users log into their own Google Calendar and then come back to the shared calendar and refresh the page, it works for them.